# Selecting certain value from row based on another value in same row

Tags: sql

I have a following table with following data:

Table

[image]

Now I want to get all those users (distinct only) who do not have value 5 in Column B. What I mean is user1 has a value 5 in some row, then all user 1 rows are dismissed.

Following result should be produced:
user2 (because value is null)
user3 (no value 5)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be aggregation by user:

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ColumnB = 5 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is aggregation:

```
select columnA
from t
group by columnA
having sum(case when columnB = 5 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...so it sounds like it may take them a while (unlike 100K, which was basically automatic).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by Minus operator

```
SELECT distinct colA
FROM have
WHERE colB not in(5)
MINUS
SELECT distinct colA 
FROM have
WHERE colB=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NOT EXISTS` you can able to get the result

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ColumnA
FROM TableName T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM TableName T2 WHERE T2.ColumnA = T1.ColumnA AND T2.ColumnB <> 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way -

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ColumnA
FROM TableName T1
WHERE T1.ColumnA NOT IN 
(
   SELECT T2.ColumnA FROM TableName T2 WHERE T2.ColumnB = 5
)
```